# SwiftUI: How to add Blur view with app logo when app in background?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am new to SwiftUI. I am trying to add blur view with the app logo when the app enters into the background for hiding secure information. I tried the below code. It's showing blur as expected. But I want to display the view+app logo.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @Environment(\.scenePhase) var scenePhase
    @State var blurRadius : CGFloat = 0
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            MainView()
        }.blur(radius: blurRadius)
            .onChange(of: scenePhase, perform: { value in
                switch value {
                case .active : withAnimation { blurRadius = 0 }
                case .inactive: withAnimation { blurRadius = 15 }
                case .background:
                    blurRadius = 20
                @unknown default: print("Unknown")
                }
            })
    }
}
```

Result:

[image]

Someone please suggests how to achieve that?

Comment: Thanks! Your question already has all I need, I don't need to show app logo when going to background, I just needed to hide sensitive data. Thanks for your solution :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a `ZStack` and place your logo image on top whenever there's a blur in place:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @Environment(\.scenePhase) var scenePhase
    @State var blurRadius : CGFloat = 0
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            VStack{
                MainView()
            }
            .blur(radius: blurRadius)
            .onChange(of: scenePhase, perform: { value in
                switch value {
                case .active : withAnimation { blurRadius = 0 }
                case .inactive: withAnimation { blurRadius = 15 }
                case .background:
                    blurRadius = 20
                @unknown default: print("Unknown")
                }
            })
            if blurRadius != 0 {
                Image("logo")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is assuming your app logo is added to the project's assets as "logo". Obviously, you may want to do some modifications like `.resizable` or `.frame` on the `Image`

Answer (score -1):

Honestly I suppose that previous answer is a bad solution. You should copy on every screen it. Try this:

```
static let appWindow = UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes.map({ $0 as? UIWindowScene }).compactMap({ $0 }).first?.windows.first
```

Then just add it on the tabBar, or on the main `ContentView`:

```
@Environment(\.scenePhase) var scenePhase
@State private var coverImage: UIVisualEffectView?

    private func addBluredView() {
    coverImage = UIVisualEffectView(effect: UIBlurEffect(style: .systemChromeMaterialDark))
    if let coverImage {
        coverImage.frame = AppInfo.appWindow!.screen.bounds
        AppSettings.appWindow?.addSubview(coverImage)
    }
}
```

and handle it:

```
        .onChange(of: scenePhase) { newPhase in
        switch newPhase {
        case .inactive:
            addBluredView()
        case .active:
            coverImage?.removeFromSuperview()
        @unknown default:
            break
        }
    }
```

Comment: "Honestly I suppose that previous answer is a bad solution.  You should copy on every screen it."  

I assume you're saying it's a bad solution since it needs to be copied on every screen?  If that's the case, that is not correct.  

If the accepted solution is added to the root view of the application it will affect the entire app in one place.  I'd argue that you're solution is the "bad" one since it unnecessarily relies on `UIKit`